# Where is the bluetooth antenna located in iPhones?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I posted [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27560622#27560622) question on the Apple support forum, but no one could give me an answer.

I am researching iBeacons for my final year project at University and I'm interested to know the position of the Bluetooth antenna in the iPhones.

Can anybody give me a reliable source explaining where the bluetooth antenna is located on the different versions of the iPhones? iPhone 4S up to 6 plus.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are teardown/repair guides at [iFixIt](http://www.ifixit.com/), they note where the chips and antennas are located.

For example, in an iPhone 4S teardown, [here's a photo](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+4S+Teardown/6610#s28325) of the Wi-Fi/Bluetooth chip.
There is a guide on [replacing the upper antenna](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+4S+Upper+Antenna+Replacement/7288) - which is the [Wi-Fi/Bluetooth one](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/iPhone/iPhone-4S-Wi-Fi-Bluetooth-Antenna/IF115-018).
And there is also [a step-by-step guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+Fix+iPhone+4S+Wi-Fi+Grayed+Out/22167) on fixing the wi-fi which provides the detailed photos and description.

It appears that the Bluetooth antenna is located at the top of the 4S. The [discussion](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+6+Teardown/29213#c132100) of the iPhone 6 teardown also states that the Apple fit the antenna on the top.

So, iFixit has a lot of manuals and photos to provide. Also, they've got a great community, so if you have any further questions, you can ask them instead.

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for the quick response! Yes I came across them before, but I was hoping for a more reliable source such as Apple. I assume they don't release it though :/

Comment: @smj2393 sadly, Apple is a pretty much _private_ company in that case. :(

Comment: Ok cheers, guess I will have to use iFixIt then!

Answer (score -1):

Its on the top as when you block that area of the phone the bluetooth stops working